# What does a method with the same name as its class do?

Tags: php, class, methods

I was wondering what is accomplished by having a method as the same name of the class. Does it work like a constructor? Here is an example:

```
class Foo {

  function Foo(){
    //do something.
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does it work like a constructor?

It did, and still does for backwards computability, but the correct way to define a constructor from PHP 5 and onwards is to define a method called [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).

Answer (score 1):

In < PHP5 it acts as a constructor. In PHP5+, for backward compatibility, it still works this way, but is deprecated. In PHP5+ you should use `__construct( )` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would define a class constructor in PHP4.. though it is still valid for backward compatability it is deprecated and for PHP5 should use __construct()

Try this to make your class compatible with PHP4 and PHP5

```
  class foo {
//forward php4 to constructor
function foo() {

    return $this->__construct();
}

//constructor php5
function __construct() {

    register_shutdown_function(array(&$this, "__destruct"));
}
```

}